# How do I get the max number of blocks per SM for a cooperative group launch?

Tags: cupy

Cuda cooperative group launches must ensure that all threads are launched instantaneously in order for [grid synchronization](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization) to work.

```cpp
/// This will launch a grid that can maximally fill the GPU, on the default stream with kernel arguments
int numBlocksPerSm = 0;
 // Number of threads my_kernel will be launched with
int numThreads = 128;
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(&numBlocksPerSm, my_kernel, numThreads, 0);
// launch
void *kernelArgs[] = { /* add kernel args */ };
dim3 dimBlock(numThreads, 1, 1);
dim3 dimGrid(deviceProp.multiProcessorCount*numBlocksPerSm, 1, 1);
cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)my_kernel, dimGrid, dimBlock, kernelArgs);
```

I want to understand how it would be possible to the calculate the max active blocks per SM as in the above fragment from the Cuda guide with CuPy.

```py
import cupy as cp

# Get the current device
device = cp.cuda.Device()

# Define the block size
block_size = 256

# Compile a sample kernel and get the number of registers per thread
kernel_code = '''
extern "C" __global__ void mykernel(float *x, float *y, float *z) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    z[tid] = x[tid] + y[tid];
}
'''
module = cp.RawModule(code=kernel_code, backend='nvcc')
kernel = module.get_function('mykernel')
regs_per_thread = kernel.attributes['num_regs']

# Define the shared memory per block
shared_mem_per_block = kernel.shared_size_bytes

# Get the maximum number of blocks per SM
max_blocks_per_sm = device.max_blocks_per_sm(block_size, regs_per_thread, shared_mem_per_block)

# Print the result
print(f'The maximum number of blocks per SM is {max_blocks_per_sm}')
```

I asked Bing for help, but it hallucinated the `max_blocks_per_sm` method. Does an API method to calculate the occupancy exist somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```py
max_blocks_per_sm = min(
    device.attributes['MaxBlocksPerMultiprocessor'],
    device.attributes['MaxThreadsPerMultiProcessor'] // block_size,
    device.attributes['MaxRegistersPerMultiprocessor'] // (regs_per_thread * block_size),
    device.attributes['MaxSharedMemoryPerMultiprocessor'] // shared_mem_per_block,
    )
```

I am not 100% sure if this is right, but after cleaning up an error in the formula Bing gave me, I came up with a manual calculation as you can see in the code fragment. It makes sense, so I think I'll use this unless somebody points me to an inbuilt method for calculating the max number of blocks per SM.

Here is a cleaned-up example that avoids division by zero:

```py
# Get the maximum number of blocks per SM
def max_blocks_per_sm(device, kernel, block_size):
    def floordiv(a,b): return a // b if b != 0 else device.attributes['MaxBlocksPerMultiprocessor']

    # Define the regs per thread.
    regs_per_thread = kernel.num_regs

    # Define the shared memory per block
    shared_mem_per_block = kernel.shared_size_bytes

    return min(
        device.attributes['MaxBlocksPerMultiprocessor'],
        floordiv(device.attributes['MaxThreadsPerMultiProcessor'], block_size),
        floordiv(device.attributes['MaxRegistersPerMultiprocessor'], regs_per_thread * block_size),
        floordiv(device.attributes['MaxSharedMemoryPerMultiprocessor'], shared_mem_per_block),
        )

import cupy as cp

# Get the current device
device = cp.cuda.Device()


# Compile a sample kernel and get the number of registers per thread
kernel_code = '''
extern "C" __global__ void mykernel(float *x, float *y, float *z) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    z[tid] = x[tid] + y[tid];
}
'''
module = cp.RawModule(code=kernel_code, backend='nvcc')
kernel = module.get_function('mykernel')

# Define the block size
block_size = 256

# Print the result
print(f'The maximum number of blocks per SM is {max_blocks_per_sm(device, kernel, block_size)}')
```